Predicting FPL Player Total Points using Random Forest
I have a dataset with around 100k of gameweek stats in the English Premier League (from 2016-2023). My goal is to predict how many total points a player will score in a certain gameweek/match.
I divided the data into train/test set, with the train set containing stats for the seasons < 2022 and the test set containing stats for the seasons > 2022.
To account for current form of a certain player, I calculated rolling average values over the last 3 gameweeks for the following variables:
goals_scord, assists, clean_sheets, goals_conceded, minutes, own_goals, penalties_saved, penalties_missed, yellow_cards, red_cards, saves, influence, creativity, threat and ict_index
I then run the random forest with these variables and some additional variables:
was_home, player_team, opponent_team, opponent_strength, element_type (defender/midfielder etc)
The model looks like this:
rf <- randomForest(
      as.formula(paste(target, "~", paste(predictors, collapse = " + "))),
      data = train,
      ntree = 500,
      mtry = 7,
      nodesize = 10,
      importance = TRUE)

Doing this I only get an R^2 of around 57%. So my question is if this is normal or if I have made mistakes in my methodology? I wonder where I can improve the model and if machine learning is a good way of predicting total points at all?

If your response is essentially random, then (almost?) all models will have a poor fit.  If there's a high element of chance in how many "points" your player will score, then, maybe, 57% is as good as you can get.  And besides, there are other measures of model fit that might be more informative.  As this isn't really a programming question, I'm voting to migrate.
